# Lipschitz Continuity of the Value Function

Tags: optimization, continuity, lipschitz-functions

Suppose that $g:[0,1]^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a smooth function. Define the value function
$$ g^*(x) = \max_{t \in [0,1]} g(x,t). $$

Question: Under what conditions would $g^*$ be a Lipschitz continuous function?

Thanks in advance for any help! Any reference would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Pardon me : I'd attached an earlier reference that contained mere continuity of the function. However, there exist stronger conditions under which $g^*$ is differentiable. Now, if that did occur, then $g^*$ would obviously be Lipschitz given domain conditions , so I'll put it out as a really minor sufficient condition : I asked about the stronger condition of differentiability [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3942536/differentiating-the-maximum) from where you can pick up references to Danskin's theorem.

Comment: Interesting, I am exactly looking at your question (while trying to find duplicate, which I failed...) @SarveshRavichandranIyer

Comment: @ArcticChar Not sure that one is an exact duplicate, although I cannot rule others. If I had to offer an argument : the difference between sufficient conditions for continuity and differentiability of the maximum are far apart. Berge's theorem assumes very little , while Danskin's theorem is quite rigid in comparison.

Comment: @ArcticChar Yes, it does. Thanks!

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer Having differentiability is very helpful! Thank you!

Comment: @WaitedLeastSquare Welcome, I'm happy it worked out somehow.